# Import Wide World Importers DB into Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure

I would like to import the sample `WideWorldImporters-Full.bacpac` database from:

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/wide-world-importers-v1.0/WideWorldImportersDW-Standard.bacpac

into Azure Data Studio 1.32 for Windows 10. I am using the Data-tier Application Wizard -> Create a DB from a .bacpac file. I get the following error which has stumped me:

```
Import bacpac: Could not import package.
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'WideWorldImportersDW-Standard_USERDATA_B694BC2.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE (NAME = [USERDATA_B694BC2], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_USERDATA_B694BC2.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [USERDATA];


Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5009, Level 16, State 8, Line 1 One or more files listed in the statement could not be found or could not be initialized.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE (NAME = [USERDATA_B694BC2], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_USERDATA_B694BC2.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [USERDATA];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't import (or restore) a database into ADS; it's just an IDE. You need to put restore it to your Instance.

Comment: I am using the official guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-dacpac-extension?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-dacpac-extension?view=sql-server-ver15) and was able to import the `WideWorldImporters-Full.bacpac` database successfully using **Azure data studio**.

Please make sure you provide correct file location in **Step2** to import the dacpac file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you configure the underlying DB? I'm using the latest Docker image for SQL Server...Or can Azure handle that?